# Why does Rust appear to execute statements/expressions out of order when using `print!`?

Tags: rust

This Rust program seems to be doing things out of order - not line-by-line. I'm sure there's an explanation, but I am having trouble finding the knowledge.

Can you point me toward some documentation on what order Rust decides to run things, or explain why this little program runs in the order that it does?

Thanks!

```
use std::{time, thread};

fn main() {
    let sleep_time: u64 = 4000;
    let sleep_duration = time::Duration::from_millis(sleep_time);

    println!("there is a delay after printing this line. makes sense.");
    thread::sleep(sleep_duration);

    println!("there is a delay after printing this line. why?");
    // there is no sleep command here, so why is it acting like it's sleeping again?

    print!("but there is no delay after printing this line...");
    thread::sleep(sleep_duration); // this sleep command is ignored?
    println!("why?");
}
```